# How to turn array into quote and comma delimited string for sql?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list I want to pass into SQL but they must be single quote and comma delimited.

So `List = a b c`

But I need a `string = 'a','b','c'`

How can I accomplish this in a concise manner?

Something like this I think but can't see within LINQ how to add to beginning and end:

```
String.Join(",", arr.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Comment: In what format the original list is available?

Comment: The original list is a List<string> where I've used .Add to update values to it.

Comment: `String.Join(",", arr.Select(p=> "'" + p.ToString() + "'").ToArray())`?

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), e.g. to produce a string of values to use in an [`in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause or to store a CSV string in a horribly denormalized way. There may be a much better way to solve the _real problem_.

Comment: The `.ToArray()` is redundant.

Comment: @MarkMcGown you know you can easily do that with a loop, but you want solution in `Linq` only. right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
String.Join(",", arr.Select(p=> "'" + p.ToString() + "'").ToArray());

// or is p already a string

String.Join(",", arr.Select(p => "'" + p + "'").ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
String.Join(",", arr.Select(p => $"'{p.ToString()}'").ToArray());
```

And that will put the `'` on either side of `p.ToString()` for each element.

Comment: CS1056: Unexpected character '$' and I think you are missing right parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

Use an ORM that supports the following construction:

```
string[] items = GetItems();
var query = db.Rows.Where(row => items.Contains(row.ColumnName));
```

This way, you do not open yourself to sql injection by constructing strings to hand to the database yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should also be careful if your source data contains `"'"` in which case you need to escape the `"'"`. Try this:

```
var arr = new [] { "a'c", "b" };

var output = String.Join(",", arr.Select(p => $"'{p.Replace("'", "''")}'"));
```

That gives `"'a''c','b'"`.